# error when using linqkit's predicate with an expression method

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011, linqkit

**A little background:**
I'm using a Linq provider ([MsCrm2011 Linq provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681573.aspx), but doesn't really matter) that doesn't support certain operations.
Specifically, it doesn't support `Contains()` inside an expression.
Meaning- something like this will not work: `var users = DataContext.Users.Where(user => userIds.Contains(user.Id))`.

[The solution I've found](http://www.crmcodex.com/2011/12/tip-getting-around-a-contains-issue-in-linq-for-mscrm2011/) for it was to use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)'s predicate, so instead of `userIds.Contains(...)` I'll have `user.Id == userIds[0] || user.Id == userIds[1] ... || user.Id == userIds[100]`.

To this end, I've defined the following function, which takes an arbitrary collection and arbitrary expression, and applies the 'Or' on them:

```
private IQueryable<TCrmEntity> FilterByCollection<TCrmEntity, T>(IQueryable<TCrmEntity> entities, IEnumerable<T> collection, Expression<Func<TCrmEntity, T, bool>> filterFunction)
    {
      var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<TCrmEntity>();
      predicate = collection.Aggregate(predicate, (current, collectionElement) => current.Or(entity => filterFunction.Invoke(entity,collectionElement)));

      var query = entities.AsExpandable()
        .Where(predicate);

      return query;
    }
```

this way, I can use any kind of collection and any kind of expression.
For example, see this test run (using an in-memory users collection): `var res = FilterByCollection(users.AsQueryable(), rolesList, (account, role) => account.Role == role)` to find all users that have one of the given roles.

However, I'm getting the following exception when I'm running the above example- `variable 'entity' of type 'User' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined`.

Any ideas?

P.S. not sure how relevant this is, but when I'm actually using the Crm data context instead of an in-memory collection, I'm not getting this error. :/